# Code for limiting password characters

Tags: java, string, char

I'm still relatively new to Java and wanted to try out some new stuff related to strings. I tried to write a code for the user to enter a password between 4-12 characters, and so far it worked fine. But during the process, I had to make little fixes here and there, and honestly it does look pretty messy, like a puzzle where all pieces fit but don't make one whole picture. I want my code to be something more "optimized" so I can have an idea of how codes like this one works, you know, just for future reference. So any help appreciated, please take a look at my code and see if there's anything that can be improved. Thanks!

```
import static java.lang.System.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PasswordWithLimit {

public static void main (String[] args){
    Scanner scan = new Scanner (in);

    out.print("Enter your password(4-12 characters): ");
    String pass = scan.nextLine () + "            ";
    char check = pass.charAt (11);
    if (pass.indexOf (" ") == 3){
        out.println("Please enter a valid password: ");
    }
    if (Character.isSpaceChar(check) || Character.isWhitespace(check)){
        out.println("Your password is " + pass);
    }
    else{
        out.println("Please enter a valid password");

    }
}

}
```

Comment: What are the rules?

Comment: Hint: Maybe you can use a regex to match valid passwords and remove some of the if-blocks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using the String's length property. This example prompts the user to enter their password and continues asking them until they have entered something which meets the requirements.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter your password (4 to 12 characters)"); // Prompt the user

    boolean valid = false;
    while (!valid) {
        String password = in.nextLine();
        if (password.length() > 3 && password.length() < 13) {
            valid = true; // Length between 4 and 12, we can stop asking.
            System.out.println("Your password is " + password);
        } else {
            System.out.print("Please enter a valid password: "); // Invalid length, ask again.
        }
    }

    in.close();
}
```

Comment: Jesus, I forgot about it! When I first wrote the thing I had the idea of checking for blank space characters, and also focused on the charAt() thing, and forgot about the string.length(). Thanks